# Cant connect my site to my Access DB on the server

Tags: asp.net, ms-access, connection-string

I'm trying to connect my site to that DB
and this is the error its shows:

```
System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: Internet Server Error: Object/module not found.
at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandTextErrorHandling(OleDbHResult hr)
at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandTextForSingleResult(tagDBPARAMS dbParams, Object& executeResult)
at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandText(Object& executeResult)
at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteReaderInternal(CommandBehavior behavior, String method)
at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
at DAL.ExecuteNonQuery(String strSql) in c:\ainProject3\App_Code\DAL.cs:line 102
```

this is my connection string:

```
Provider=MS Remote; Remote Server=http://89.64.257.131; Remote Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=C:\ainProject3\App_Data\db2.mdb
```

Answer (score 0):

seems like this isn't a common (or good) scenario for accessing an access database

see this [article](http://databases.aspfaq.com/database/why-can-t-i-access-a-database-or-text-file-on-another-server.html) for tips on how to make it work.

I suggest its probably a good idea to look at moving to something a bit more robust than Access

Comment: Access/Jet/ACE is fine in many contexts, but behind a web server, it's entirely inappropriate, except for very low-volume sites with few writes/updates.